# Saving and retrieving images with correct order

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, xcode7, swift-array

I'm trying save some images to an array, and their name to another array as string with below code;

```
self.countryNamesArray.append(object["CountryName"] as! String)
let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
self.countryImages.append(image!)
```

But it doesn't retrieve images with same order I saved while retrieve CountryNamesArray with correct order.

```
rowString = countryNamesArray[row]
myImageView.image = self.countryImages[row]
```

Should I use custom class to save images with string or are there any way to fix?

Comment: Yes, making a class - or better, a struct - to hold your values (and making a single array of these objects) is a good idea anyway.

Comment: I'll try to use custom class. Thanks Eric.